# Is there a way to "export as" on flutter? - Correct way to create a 'library'

Tags: flutter, dart, import, package, export

I want to have all the import packages of my project in one file so I import that file everywhere.

I created `imports.dart`, I export all packages but I don't know how to do it when I need to add a tag, like: `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

When I write `export 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can import any package like http package. You don't need to export it with another name.

Let's say you made a package with a class named "CidQu" then you want to use this package in your code. You can simply use

```
import 'package:my_package/package.dart';

variable = CidQu().func;
```

But if you use "import as", your class needs to start with another name.

```
import 'package:my_package/package.dart' as defne;

variable = defne.CidQu().func;
```

That's all matters, you don't need to export with another name. And I believe there is nothing called "export as".